# Generate canvas replication(jpg/img) from dataURL

Tags: jquery, facebook, canvas, kineticjs, data-uri

I'd like to be able to make a little page where the user can use the drag and drop to place objects on a scene then save their canvas as an image, or post the image to facebook/pinterest.

I have created the drag and drop and the dataURI feature using the KineticJS library based on the Animals on a beach example merged with the drag and drop save image feature.

What I really would like to be able to do is place the canvas image into an image holder on the same (or new) page (for example, [here using the Canvas2imageJS doc](http://hongru.github.com/proj/canvas2image/index.html)). I have been able to make the save feature open the image in a new window and also produce the string for the dataURI as text in a text box as shown [here on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleerin/53RjG/) (or code including a blank space holder below ) where clicking the save button opens the image (dataURI) in a new (smaller) window and also generates the string for the dataURI.

> body {
>           margin: 0px;
>           padding: 0px;
>         }
>         canvas {
>           border: 1px solid #9C9898;
>         }
>         #buttons {
>           position: absolute;
>           left: 10px;
>           top: 0px;
>         }
>         button {
>           margin-top: 10px;
>           display: block;
>
> ```
>   }
>     #imgArea{ border: 2px solid red; min-width: 576px; min-height:200px; display: block;}
> </style>
> <script src="http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/libraries/kinetic-v4.0.3.js"></script>
> <script>
>   window.onload = function() {
>     var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
>       container: 'container',
>       width: 578,
>       height: 200
>     });
>     var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
>     var rectX = stage.getWidth() / 2 - 50;
>     var rectY = stage.getHeight() / 2 - 25;
>
>     var box = new Kinetic.Rect({
>       x: rectX,
>       y: rectY,
>       width: 100,
>       height: 50,
>       fill: '#00D2FF',
>       stroke: 'black',
>       strokeWidth: 4,
>       draggable: true
>     });
>
>     box.on('mouseover', function() {
>       document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
>     });
>
>     box.on('mouseout', function() {
>       document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
>     });
>
>     layer.add(box);
>     stage.add(layer);
>
>     document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('click', function() {
>       stage.toDataURL({
>         callback: function(dataUrl) {
>     document.getElementById("textArea").value = dataUrl;
>
>           window.open(dataUrl, "toDataURL() image", "width=600, height=200");
>         }
>
>       });
>     }, false);
>   };
>
> </script>   </head>   <body>
> <div id="container"></div>
> <div id="buttons">
>   <button id="save">
>     Save as image
>   </button>
> </div><div style="">
>   <textarea rows="10" cols="60" id="textArea"></textarea><br>
>   Your picture will appear here:
>
>   <img id="imgArea"/></div>
>
>      </body> </html>
> ```

Could anyone please help me understand how to make the result of the clicking the button so that the generated image can be shared/posted to facebook / pinterest wall? 
My work in progress is also here (drag and drop and generates the dataURI in a new window only): www.shugar.com.au/obar/Default4.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, don't do window.open(dataURL);

take the dataURL and do something else with it, like AJAX it to Facebook.

I forget the exact syntax but it goes something like this:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: facebook.com/myaccountUpload/somethingsomething, //here you need the url to upload it to Facebook
    data: dataURL,
    success: function(response){
       alert('uploaded to Facebook');
    },
    error: .... console.log(error);
 });
```